# Since what version of php can you directly access a property of an object returned from a function?

Tags: php, oop

Since what version of php can you directly access a property of an object that is returned from a function?

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public $foo;

    public function __construct($foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

}

function bar() {
    return new Foo(1);
}

echo bar()->foo;
```

Comment: You need to access with static method.

Comment: from php 5.4 you can do `methodThatReturnsArray()['someIndex];`

Comment: @DanielChernenkov reread the question. I think you mis-read the `bar()` function.

Comment: @jcsanyi yup. sorry, I missed the point

Comment: It's supported from php 5.0.

Comment: @PLB so, from the very beginning of new object model?

Comment: @v6024i AFAIK, yes. In php 4 this kind of usage should trigger syntax error saying that you have invalid object operator if I remember it properly..

Answer (score 2):

Object oriented programming (OOP) was first introduced in php4. Area for oop in php version 4 was not very vast. There were only few features  available in php4. Major concept of the object oriented programming in PHP is introduced from version 5 (we commonly known as php5).